# How to tell if an out parameter was set already?

Tags: c#, out

Is there a way to know if an out parameter was set already or not.  This is the pseudocode for what I am looking for:

```
public virtual string blabla(long num, out bool bval)
    {
        if (!bval.HasValue)
            {
            //Do some default logic
            bval = defaultValue;
            }

        return blabla2(num, bval);
    }
```

Comment: If you expect something to come in the method, not only to go out, then use 'ref' instead of 'out'.

Comment: Looks like you need a nullable type : `ref bool? bval`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't - you can't *read* the variable until it's been definitely assigned within your method. You should think of it as being like a local variable, declared but not assigned any value at the start of the method - but which you *must* assign a value to before you return. (It's okay not to have assigned a value to it if an exception is thrown.)

If you want a parameter which carries information as *input* to the method as well as propagating information out, you should use `ref` instead of `out`.

See [my article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more information.

Comment: An out parameter is more suitable in my case. But I was just checking to see if there is some way to check if a value has been assigned. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Omtara: What *exactly* do you mean by "if a value has been assigned"? Do you mean outside the method, or within your own method? If you mean within your own method, you could track it with a separate `bool` local variable yourself. It's odd not to know just by where you are in the code in most places though.

Comment: @Omtara - how is an out parameter more suitable when in the comment you're saying that an outer method from where the current method is called is using the same out parameter ?

Comment: @Joanna: I ended up changing the logic a bit to make it work with the out parameter. However, as @ henk-holterman suggested, a ref Nullable<bool> is a good way of knowing if it was set or not.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Jon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366405/452274) excellent answer, if you want the parameter to still be `out`, but need to see if it has been assigned a value at some place inside the method, you could use a local nullable type like follows:

```
public virtual string blabla(long num, out bool bval)
{
    bool? bvalLocal;

    ... //I'm assuming there is some code here that may or 
        //may not assign bvalLocal?

    // This whole if block may not be needed if the default
    // value is the default for the type (i.e. false) as
    // GetValueOrDefualt() will take care of that (see 
    // second to last line).
    if (!bvalLocal.HasValue)
    {
        //Do some default logic
        bvalLocal = defaultValue;
    }

    bval = bvalLocal.GetValueOrDefault();
    return blabla2(num, bval);
}
```

Comment: The method that needs to check an out parameter is called from another method that uses the same out parameter. So using a local nullable variable would not work.

Comment: @Omtara - it might help if you posted the code (or pseudocode) of those method calls